# How to make new home page entry point to old blog post

Tags: wordpress

I have a trading blog showing stock trades I make. Each post represents a trade and it will be updated over time as the trade is happening.

For example, a post is created when I buy a stock. A new entry appears on the home page. A few weeks later, I buy more shares and update the same post. I want a new entry to appear on the home page indicating an existing trade has an update.

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different plugins, like posts carousels, post-based portfolios, etc. I'm sure with a little configuration almost all of them have an option to push recently updated posts to the beginning.